# Cannot read property 'match' or undefined truffle console

Tags: solidity, truffle, tokens

I want to interact with my contracts through truffle console. I am using test rpc and web3.

Basically for a standard token contract:

```
contract Token{
       function Token() payable{...}
       function _transfer(...) internal {...}
       function transfer (..) payable{..}
}
```

i use those command lines in the truffle console:

```
var contract=null;

Token.new({ from: web3.eth.accounts[0], value: web3.toWei(100, "ether") }).then(function(_contract) { contract = _contract; });

contract.transfer('address of another testrpc accounts', 10, { from: web3.eth.accounts[0], value: web3.toWei(100, "ether") })
```

Then i got a "Cannot read property 'match' or undefined truffle console" error.

I am lost now because the getters of my contract are actually working.. (ex: token.get_balance.call(..)  )

Any idea? Does the syntax of truffle console has changed recently?

Thks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you need to specify the **to** field in the data.

So if you were to move funds from your coinbase account to your second account you would do:

```
contract.transfer(web3.eth.accounts[1], 10, { from: web3.eth.accounts[0],to:web3.eth.accounts[0], value: web3.toWei(100, "ether") })
```